# How to track the referral chain in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns. The data will be captured via google forms.

Here a person fills and submits a form with his Name and cell no Then he has to send (Refer) the form link to another person to fill. This person will fill his name and cell no and also fill the details of the person who forwarded the form to him.  Then he forwards this another person...........So the chain goes on.

I need help in finding the person who has the  longest referral chain and the names of the persons whom he has referred.  Here a person can have two separate chains but only the longest is required

Also if I could get the count of referrals by each person separately it will be helpful

Here is the link to the sample sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kVuyJa9mI-UIUK4PGobR8apCbH2B8wF85O5HNPSwB2Q/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate you help

I tried using Vlookup but was not successful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I used Vlookup and got the chains. I need help in assigning the chain level number. Some of them may have more than one chains. Please refer to sandeep.testing sheet